# bash script how to change date with hrs format and add missing days with copy of above line

Tags: command-line, bash, csv

I have csv file with data:

```
"smth","txt","33","01-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","33","02-06-2015 09:06"
"smth","txt","34","03-06-2015 09:54"
"smth","txt","34","04-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","33","05-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","32","07-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","30","08-06-2015 10:26"
"smth","txt","31","09-06-2015 12:09"
"smth","txt","30","10-06-2015 13:17"
```

it should have 30 lines as 30 days of june. There is missing 06-06-2015 and from 11-30-06-2015. I need to put line after 05-06-2015 with data from this line to 06-06-2015 and add missing data from 11-30 june with same data as 10-06-2015.

output csv file format should look like this:

```
smth#txt#33#2015-06-01
```

field with number 33 is random so it cannot be always 33

**update 22-06-2015**

some of my csv files have data like:

```
"smth","txt","33","01-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","33","02-06-2015 09:06"
"smth","txt","34","03-06-2015 09:54"
"smth","txt","34","04-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","33","05-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","32","07-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","30","08-06-2015 10:26"
"smth","txt","31","09-06-2015 12:09"
"smth","txt","30","10-06-2015 13:17"
"smth2","txt","33","01-06-2015 00:00"
"smth2","txt","33","02-06-2015 09:06"
"smth2","txt","34","03-06-2015 09:54"
"smth2","txt","34","04-06-2015 00:09"
"smth2","txt","33","05-06-2015 00:09"
"smth2","txt","32","07-06-2015 00:09"
"smth2","txt","30","08-06-2015 10:26"
"smth2","txt","31","09-06-2015 12:09"
"smth2","txt","30","10-06-2015 13:17"
```

so result should be like:

01-30 06-2015 of "smth" and 01-30 06-2015 of "smth2"

below is example (dont look at numbers in column 3, it should work as u made it)

```
smth#txt#33#2015-06-01
smth#txt#33#2015-06-02
smth#txt#33#2015-06-03
smth#txt#33#2015-06-04
smth#txt#33#2015-06-05
smth#txt#33#2015-06-06
smth#txt#33#2015-06-07
smth#txt#33#2015-06-08
smth#txt#33#2015-06-09
smth#txt#33#2015-06-10
smth#txt#33#2015-06-11
smth#txt#33#2015-06-12
smth#txt#33#2015-06-13
smth#txt#33#2015-06-14
smth#txt#33#2015-06-15
smth#txt#33#2015-06-16
smth#txt#33#2015-06-17
smth#txt#33#2015-06-18
smth#txt#33#2015-06-19
smth#txt#33#2015-06-20
smth#txt#33#2015-06-21
smth#txt#33#2015-06-22
smth#txt#33#2015-06-23
smth#txt#33#2015-06-24
smth#txt#33#2015-06-25
smth#txt#33#2015-06-26
smth#txt#33#2015-06-27
smth#txt#33#2015-06-28
smth#txt#33#2015-06-29
smth#txt#33#2015-06-30
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-01
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-02
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-03
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-04
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-05
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-06
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-07
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-08
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-09
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-10
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-11
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-12
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-13
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-14
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-15
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-16
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-17
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-18
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-19
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-20
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-21
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-22
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-23
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-24
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-25
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-26
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-27
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-28
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-29
smth2#txt#33#2015-06-30
```

pls help me with that, show me path to create bash script makes my life easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ruby solution. It does not matter if the first record of your data is the first of the month.

```rb
require 'date'
require 'csv'

# store the data in a hash, keyed by date
new = {}
data = CSV.parse(File.read(ARGV.shift))
data.each do |row|
  d = DateTime.parse(row[-1])
  new[d.to_date] = row
end

# fill in all the missing dates for this month
row = data[0]
d = DateTime.parse(row[-1])
date = Date.new(d.year, d.month, 1)
while date.month == d.month
  if new.has_key?(date)
    row = new[date]
  else
    new[date] = row[0..-2] + [date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")]
  end
  date += 1
end

# print the CSV
new.keys.sort.each do |key|
  puts CSV.generate_line(new[key], :force_quotes=>true)
end
```

Run it like: `ruby program.rb file.csv`

outputs

```
"smth","txt","33","01-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","33","02-06-2015 09:06"
"smth","txt","34","03-06-2015 09:54"
"smth","txt","34","04-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","33","05-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","33","06-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","32","07-06-2015 00:09"
"smth","txt","30","08-06-2015 10:26"
"smth","txt","31","09-06-2015 12:09"
"smth","txt","30","10-06-2015 13:17"
"smth","txt","30","11-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","12-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","13-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","14-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","15-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","16-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","17-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","18-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","19-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","20-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","21-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","22-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","23-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","24-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","25-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","26-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","27-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","28-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","29-06-2015 00:00"
"smth","txt","30","30-06-2015 00:00"
```

---

A GNU awk version.

```
BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}

{
    datetime = gensub(/^"|"$/, "", "g", $NF) 
    split(datetime, a, /[- :]/)
    day = mktime( a[3] " " a[2] " " a[1] " 0 0 0" )
    data[day] = $0
}

NR == 1 { 
    month = strftime("%m", day) 
    year = strftime("%Y", day) 
    row = $0
}

END {
    mday = 1
    while ( (day = mktime(year " " month " " mday++ " 0 0 0")) 
            && strftime("%m", day) == month
    ) {
        if (day in data) {
            $0 = row = data[day]
        }
        else {
            $0 = row
            $NF = strftime("\"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M\"", day)
        }
        print
    }
}
```

Comment: ruby version work almost perfect but if i have in csv file in column "smth" for example "smth2" it make only these on end of file. Only "smth2".

Comment: It should be copying the values from the last row. What do you want?

Comment: yes i know that it copy from last row but some csv files have data like: from 01-30 06-2015 with "smth" on first column and from 01-30 06-2015 with "smth2" on first column. So if "smth2" is below "smth" and have no 01-06-2015 then gets data from last line of "smth". Result should look like our friend bash script smth#txt#33#2015-06-01 but i can make it by sed in next script.

Comment: i can edit my question with code view that can helps... let me know

Answer (score 1):

Bash solution - too complicated for my taste, I'd reach for a more powerful language like Perl.

```
#!/bin/bash

remove_doublequotes () {
    line=("${line[@]#\"}")
    line=("${line[@]%\"}")
}

fix_timestamp () {
    line[3]=${line[3]:6:4}-${line[3]:3:2}-${line[3]:0:2}
}


read_next=0
printed=0

# Extract the date from the first line to get the number of days in the month.
IFS=, read -a line
year=${line[3]:7:4}
month=${line[3]:4:2}
day=${line[3]:1:2}
if [[ $day != 01 ]] ; then
    echo "First day missing." >&2
    exit 1
fi
cal=$(echo $(cal "$month" "$year"))
last_day=${cal##* }
remove_doublequotes
fix_timestamp

for day in $(seq 1 $last_day) ; do
    day=$(printf %02d $day)
    if (( read_next )) ; then
        if IFS=, read -a line ; then
            remove_doublequotes
            fix_timestamp
            printed=0
        else                               # Fill in the missing day at the month end.
            line=("${last_line[@]}")
        fi
    fi
    if [[ ${line[3]} == *"-$day" ]] ; then # Current line should be printed.
        (IFS=#; echo "${line[*]}")
        read_next=1
        last_line=("${line[@]}")
        printed=1
    else                                  # Fake the report.
        insert=("${last_line[@]}")
        insert[3]=${insert[3]:0:8}$day
        (IFS=#; echo "${insert[*]}")
        read_next=0                       # We still have to print the line later.
    fi
done

if (( ! printed )) ; then                 # Input contains extra lines.
    echo "Line '${line[@]}' not processed" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: it always stack and after hit any button give "First day missing." but first day is on csv file.

Comment: Did you run it as `./script.sh < input.csv`?

Comment: My bad sorry, now it runs. But sometimes there is missing 1st day of month and file starts with 02-06-2015 or 04-06-2015. Some files have in column "smth" for example "smth2" and script runs only for "smth". Ill try to modify.